# Inconsistent results when installing .rpm package

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, rpm-spec, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a `.sh` script that I packaged as `.rpm` to distribute. I'm using GitLab CI CD pipeline using `gitlab-ci.yml`. I'm able to pacakge the script in `.rpm` with no problems using the `.spec`.

The **issue** is when I install the `.rpm` *(after uploading and downloading)* in various systems for testing and make sure it does what I expect it to do.

So in the `.spec` file I specify that I want to install it in `/usr/bin/myscript.sh` with the following in `.spec` file:

```
%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}

mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_prefix}/bin
install -m 755 -p $RPM_BUILD_DIR/myscript.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_prefix}/bin/
```

So to **test** the newly created `.rpm` I try to install in 2 different containers
First one called **centos**
**Output**

```
[root@1235 /]# curl -O http://url/srpms/myscript-1.0-1.el7.src.rpm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5773  100  5773    0     0   626k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  626k
[root@1235 /]# ls
bin  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  myscript-1.0-1.el7.src.rpm
[root@1235 /]# rpm -iv myscript-1.0-1.el7.src.rpm 
myscript-1.0-1.el7.noarch
[root@1235 /]# rpm -ql xsoar*
myscript.sh
myscript.spec
[root@1235 /]# find . -type f -name "myscript.sh" 2>/dev/null
./root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myscript.sh
[root@1235 /]#
```

As you can see the script ends up in a path that was created by the installation itself `./root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/` instead of the expected `/usr/bin/`

---

For the next container I used the same **image/container** used by `gitlab-ci.yml` to package the `.rpm`
**Output**

```
[root@5704de76a68c /]# rpm -iv myscript-1.0-1.el7.src.rpm
myscript-1.0-1.el7.noarch
[root@5704de76a68c /]# rpm -ql xsoar*
package myscript-1.0-1.el7.src.rpm is not installed
[root@5704de76a68c /]# find . -type f -name "myscript.sh" 2>/dev/null
./root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myscript.sh
[root@5704de76a68c /]#
```

Similar result but it says `.rpm is not installed`

---

Then for the heck of I tried installing the `.rpm` in the same instance/container right after creation using `gitlab-ci.yml` *(before it gets uploaded to any repo for distribution)* and I do get the **expected** result
**Output**

```
$ rpm -ivh $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/*.rpm
Preparing...                          ########################################
Updating / installing...
myscript-1.0-1.el7               ########################################
$ rpm -ql myscript
/usr/bin/myscript.sh
```

Part of the **.spec**

```bash
%prep
cp -fp %{SOURCE0} ./

%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}

mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_prefix}/bin
install -m 755 -p $RPM_BUILD_DIR/myscript.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_prefix}/bin/

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%attr(755,root,root) %{_prefix}/bin/myscript.sh
```

Comment: To me this is unix & linux community question, or server fault rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: completely forgot about that, how can I rectify it?

Comment: You need to show your `%files` stanza.

Comment: added part of .spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Of course it had to be stupid. For my testing i was installing myscript.**src**.rpm instead of myscript.**noarch**.rpm